# Can we set priority_weight per task in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I know that `priority_weight` can be set for the `DAG` in the `default_args` as per the example in the official documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html?highlight=priority_weight).

Can we also set `priority_weight` that is different for each task in the `DAG`?

Following the example from the tutorial, it would mean that `t1` would have a different priority from `t2`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Can we also set priority_weight that is different for each task in the
>   DAG?

**Short Answer**

Yes

---

**Long Version**

You appear a little confused here. Citing the [passage above the snippet](https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html?highlight=priority_weight#default-arguments) in the given link:

> ..we have the choice to explicitly pass a set of arguments to each
>   task’s constructor (which would become redundant), or (better!) we can
>   define a dictionary of default parameters that we can use when
>   creating tasks..

So now you must have inferred that  The `priority_weight` that was being passed in `default_args` was actually meant for individual `task`s and not the `DAG` itself. Of course looking at the code it becomes clear that it's a [parameter of `BaseOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2508) and [not `DAG`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L3326) `SQLAlchemy` *model*

---

Also once you get to know the above fact, you'll soon realize that it wouldn't make much sense to **assign same *priority* to each `task` of `DAG`**. The said example from the official docs indeed appears to have overlooked this simple reasoning (unless I'm missing something). Nevertheless the [docstring](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2389) does seem to indicate so

> ```
> :param priority_weight: priority weight of this task against other task.
>         This allows the executor to trigger higher priority tasks before
>         others when things get backed up.
> ```

---

**UPDATE-1**

As rightly [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55145641/can-we-set-priority-weight-per-task-in-airflow/55147725?noredirect=1#comment102785242_55147725) by [@Alessandro S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898154/alessandro-s) in comments, assigning same `priority_weight` to all tasks within a DAG is NOT unreasonable after all since **`priority_weight` is not enforced on DAG-level but on `pool` level**

- So when you take 2 (or more) dags into picture (both accessing same external resource) then a valid use-case could be that you want to promote all tasks of one dag over other one
- To realize this, all tasks of first dag can be a single value of `priority_weight` which is higher than that of tasks in second dag.

Comment: Nice answer! May I ask why is it when a task depends on another, that task will have lower priority_weight. If I have 8 set of tasks, containing the series task1 >> task2 >> 3. The tendency is to always finish all task1 since they all have higher priority_weight 's. So to start set1.task2, it must finish set8.task1. Hmm. Any workaround?

Comment: Maybe explorer [`weight_rule`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L129) a bit

Comment: "it wouldn't make much sense to assign same priority to each task of DAG" --> weight is per-pool, not per-DAG so to me it still makes sense to promote tasks from one DAG inside a pool

Comment: Unfortunately, "To realize this, all tasks of first dag can be a single value of priority_weight which is higher than that of tasks in second dag." that doesn't work. If you have two different DAGs, 1 and 2 with tasks a -> b -> c. Define the default_pool to 2 and set a higher priority for all tasks of DAG 1, run both DAGs you will see that at some point tasks from DAG 2 will get executed even if DAG 1 hasn't finished yet

Answer (score 0):

In a DAG when you have multiple tasks, with upstream-downstream flow scheduler will by default assign different priorities to different tasks.

```
t1 >> t2
```

For above mentioned scenario, t1 will get higher priority weight than t2. However, t1 and t2 will have same priorities by default for following use case :

```
[t1, t2]
```

If you want to have more sophisticated and customized priority assignments. You should play around with **priority_weight** (DAG parameter) and **weight_rule** (Task parameter).

**priority_weight** can be used to prioritize all the instances of certain DAG over other DAGs.

**weight_rule** handles prioritization at task level.

For example DAG D1 has two tasks t1 and t2. t2 depends upon some parameters acquired during t1, meaning t2 should be downstream task to t1.

```
t1 >> t2
```

However, when there are multiple instances of D1 running at the same time, scheduler will run all t1 instances first and then move on to t2 instances. This is simply because by default t1 gets higher priority weight than t2. But what if you want to prioritize finishing of DAG. Meaning t2 should run after finishing corresponding t1 in all DAG instances. Then you can use **weight_rule='upstream'** to explicitly set t2 at higher priority weight than  t1.
More information [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/priority-weight.html#priority-weights)